# How can i return the Stream variable so it will not be null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public static Image favicon(String u, string file)
{
    Stream s = 
    if (!u.Contains("blank") && u != "")
    {
        Uri url = new Uri(u);
        String iconurl = "http://" + url.Host + "/favicon.ico";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(iconurl);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            s = response.GetResponseStream();
            return Image.FromStream(s);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Image.FromFile(file);
        }
    }

    return Image.FromStream(s);
}
```

The problem is that in the end s is null. So it throw exception. And i can't make instance for the Stream. Then what else can i assign for Stream s in case it return it without entering ?

Comment: "The problem is that in the end s is null." Well no, at the moment the problem is that your code won't compile. Depending on how you change the code, yes, perhaps `s` will be null. What image *do* you want to use if `u` contains "blank" or is empty?

Comment: Not sure. I'm getting exception on WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(iconurl); invalid uri cant parse. So when it's blank or empty i don't want it to try to parse it. Just don't do anything.

Comment: Well what are you going to return then? You've got to either return something or throw an exception...

Comment: "invalid uri cant parse" - what's the URI you're passing in?  Specifically, what's the value of `url.Host`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return [Stream.Null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null(v=vs.110).aspx), but you should rather handle the error right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Image favicon(string u, string file)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(u) && !u.Contains("blank"))
    {
        // Check if this is a valid URL
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(u, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            // Create the favicon.ico URL
            var url = new Uri(u);
            var iconUrl = $"http://{url.Host}/favicon.ico";

            // Try and download the icon
            var client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                return Image.FromStream(client.OpenRead(iconUrl));
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                // If there was an error download the favicon, just return the file
                return Image.FromFile(file);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter 'u' is not a valid URL");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Image.FromFile(file);
    }
}
```